# websocket send arraybuffer chrome eat huge memory to 4 GB

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, arraybuffer

I write the js code to test upload speed, the code like this, the chrome use some GB memory.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.100.67/up");
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4*1024*1024);
setInterval(function() { 
    if (ws.bufferedAmount > 10*1024*1024)
        return;
    ws.send(buffer);
    }, 10)
```

why chrome not free the memory that has been sent. after run some seconds. chrome crashed with memory exhausted.

Comment: perhaps `buffer` isn't being emptied? can't even see how it's being filled ... and why are you not sending if the buffered amount > 10MB? should that be < instead of >?

Comment: @JaromandaX, pause send, if has too many buffers waiting for sent by websocket. But the problem is why chrome use so many memories. How can I code to avoid this.

Comment: one solution - try firefox - does it gobble RAM like it's free? If firefox also eats your RAM, then there's something in the code you haven't shown that is causing either a memory leak, or you're simply not doing "something" correctly

Comment: @JaromandaX firefox uses 475 MB memory, and not increase as time. where can I post the problem to chrome developer ?

Comment: you could post minimal code here that **demonstrates** the issue

Comment: the above code could demonstrates this issue, but you need a websocket server, which can be built from: `https://github.com/yuanjianpeng/h5speedtest/tree/master` .  Click Test Upload in test page will reproduce this issuse. @JaromandaX

Comment: so, the code is supposed to send  400 megabytes of data every second? does that sound right? Also, how long does it take Chrome to gobble up your memory?

Comment: I see Chrome does eat a whole lot of RAM - does (chrome based) MS Edge (assuming you have windows 10) also misbehave like this? I know edge is chrome based, but Microdoft *claim* to make improvements, especially RAM usage

Comment: what if you change the 10ms to 100ms - does it still chew up RAM but slower?

Comment: @JaromandaX. send will stopped if buffer in websocket is larger than a value, the max speed is 400GB/s

Comment: Yes MS edge has same behave @JaromandaX

Comment: yeah, looks like yet another  "chrome memory feature" nobody wants - this sort of thing is why my company recommends people avoid chrome or chromium based browsers for our product - chrome will eat your computers memory, then will search for memory on other nodes in your LAN, then resort to your pets memory - it's the number one cause of alzheimers in the office today